# Numpy - modify values next to matched value

Tags: python, numpy

I've an image as a numpy array. I'm trying to enlarge objects with a specific color by setting any pixels next to that to the same specific color.

However, I can't find a way to this. Any suggestions how to do this?

A slightly simplified example of my question below. 
How can I find and update the values next to 12 in the array below?

```
In[1]:import numpy as np
In[2]:z = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
In[3]: z
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
   [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
   [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
   [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Resulting in an updated array which looks like this (update values in z[2,1] and z[2,3]):

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
   [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
   [10, 12, 12, 12, 14],
   [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
   [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Very thankful for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Scipy's binary dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) on the mask of the match to create a dilated mask, which could be use for `boolean-indexing` to change all neighbouring elements including the matching element itself to the matching number.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

mask = binary_dilation(z==12,[[1,1,1]]) # create dilated mask
z[mask] = 12 # use dilated mask to change elements
```

Sample run -

```
In [42]: z   # Input array
Out[42]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

In [43]: from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

In [44]: mask = binary_dilation(z==12,[[1,1,1]])

In [45]: z[mask] = 12

In [46]: z    # Input array modified
Out[46]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 12, 12, 12, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```